# Iterate through dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to iterate through a dynamic object I created to build a csv file.

Here the code where I load up the dynamic object with the csv column headers and values:

```
        int i = 0;
        MyDynamicObject myDynamicObject = new MyDynamicObject();
        TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow dr in TestActionInfoLogDT.Rows)
         {
         if (i == 0)
         { 
             myDynamicObject.SetMember("TestInfoLogID", TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[0].TestInfoLogID.Value.ToString());
             myDynamicObject.SetMember("TestInfoID", TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[0].TestInfoID.Value.ToString());
             myDynamicObject.SetMember("TestDescription", TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[0].TestDescription.ToString());
             myDynamicObject.SetMember("SPM_Barcode_UniqueValue", TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[0].ScannedInValue.ToString());
         }
         if ((bool)dr["IsScanInValueRequiredFlag"])  myDynamicObject.SetMember((string)dr["Attribute"], TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[i].ScannedInValue.ToString());
         if ((bool)dr["IsTesterScanRequiredFlag"]) myDynamicObject.SetMember((string)dr["Attribute"], TestActionInfoLogOutCS.TestActionInfoLogOutRepository[i].TesterIDSignOff.ToString());
         i++;
         }

         var props = myDynamicObject.GetDynamicMemberNames().ToList();
```

Here what myDynamicObject looks like after it's loaded:
[image]

I added the GetDynamicMemberNames override to the MyDynamicObject class:

```
 public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject
 {
     Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();


     public object GetMember(string propName)
     {
         var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
               propName, this.GetType(),
               new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)});
         var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);

         return callsite.Target(callsite, this);
     }

     public void SetMember(string propName, object val)
     {
         var binder = Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                propName, this.GetType(),
                new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)});
         var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);

         callsite.Target(callsite, this, val);
     }

     public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
     {
         string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

         return _properties.TryGetValue(name, out result);
     }

     public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
     {
         _properties[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

         return true;
     }
     public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
     {
         return from p in _properties select p.Key;
     }
```

}

I'm able to list the key property names, but need to be iterate the property values.  How do I get the values?

[image]

Ended up using the code below to load the keys and values to a class repository:

```
 TestResultsCS testResultsCS = new TestResultsCS();
   var keyList = myDynamicObject._properties.Keys.ToList();
   var valList =  myDynamicObject._properties.Values.ToList();
   for (int x = 0; x < keyList.Count - 1; x++)
   {
       testResultsCS.Attribute = keyList[x].ToString();
       testResultsCS.Value = valList[x].ToString();
       testResultsCS.LoadTestResultsRespoistory();
   }
```

I would prefer getting the values directly from the dynamic dictionary using a TryGetValue method... Attempted code below without success?

```
public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, ref TValue value)
{
    var result = dict.TryGetValue(key, out var foundValue);
    if (result) value = foundValue;
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Override [`DynamicObject.GetDynamicMemberNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames), return the relevant keys from your backing collection/dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Mathias - I was able to get the property names.  I need to get the values too.